# FlexBox Layout structure

Tags: css, flexbox

hello I'm trying to make a flexbox layout with the following css and structure:

header/main/footer
I did a little research on flex: 1 and ended up not understanding how to apply it and my footer needs to be stickey:

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <div style={{ display: "flex", flexDirection: "column", height: "100%" }}>
      <div style={{ flex: "none", background: "blue" }} />
      <div style={{ flex: "1 500px", background: "red" }} />
      <div style={{ flex: "none", background: "yellow" }} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

example:

https://codesandbox.io/s/throbbing-feather-cmxiq

basically mine I have a problem with the divs that are not appearing for some reason in my body

Comment: There's no content or height defined in the header or footer, so they are collapsing to 0 height.

Comment: Also, use `height: 100vh`, not `height: 100%`. https://stackoverflow.com/a/31728799/3597276

Comment: @Michael_B i use 100% vh on my css body > #emasanext > div {
  height: 100vh;
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The inner `div`s are all empty. And by nature, an empty `div` will collapse unless given an explicit height.

In your case, the top and bottom `div`s will end up `0px` height, because it's empty and set to not flex, and will not show up at all. The middle one has a `flex-basis` of `500px`, and thus show up as the only visible element. See below for screenshot. Either adding content or setting explicit height (or flex-basis) on header/footer will be a good start.

[image: When a text content is added]